# Get postgres table data (CSV format) in C#

Tags: c#, postgresql

CSV get query:

```
COPY (select * from a.table) TO STDOUT WITH CSV DELIMITER ';' HEADER
```

How to get query data in C#, when trying with **command.ExecuteReader()** getting an error:

```
System.Exception: Received unexpected backend message CopyOutResponse. Please file a bug.
```

Comment: This isn't a query. It's a *command* that shouldn't return any data, only status messages. It's meant to *export* data to a file on the server itself. It's *not* a way to avoid generating a CSV from query results on the client. `ExecuteReader` is used to read data rows, so it's throwing an error

Comment: *What* do you want to do anyway? Generate and store a CSV on the client? Send it to a browser? Why don't you specify a vaild file location and copy that file?

Comment: I want to send result to the client on POST request.

Comment: What data provider are you using? At least add a tag for it.

Answer (score 0):

You could always just brute force the task...

```
    private const string QUOTE = "\"";
    private const string ESCAPED_QUOTE = "\"\"";
    private static char[] CHARACTERS_THAT_MUST_BE_QUOTED = { ',', '"', '\n', '\r' };

    private static string Escape(string s)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
            return string.Empty;

        if (s.Contains(QUOTE))
            s = s.Replace(QUOTE, ESCAPED_QUOTE);

        if (s.IndexOfAny(CHARACTERS_THAT_MUST_BE_QUOTED) > -1)
            s = QUOTE + s + QUOTE;

        return s;
    }

    private void SqlToFile(string Sql, string FileName)
    {
        NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(Sql, conn);
        NpgsqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        string[] outline = new string[reader.FieldCount];

        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(FileName);

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                    outline[i] = Escape(reader.GetValue(i).ToString());

                sw.WriteLine(String.Join(",", outline));
            }

        }

        reader.Close();
        sw.Close();
    }
```

Credit owed for the `Escape` method, although I don't recall from whom I stole it.